# Smarter ordering for chat @ auto complete

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

For the gazzilionth time I mistargeted somebody in chat.

I was talking to TimStone. So I typed in `@Tim` <kbd>tab</kbd> and *kablamo* `@TimPost` got another misdirected message in his inbox.

I think a quick fix that orders the @User replies by the time last active in the room would do wonders to improve targeting.

So, if I am chatting to TimStone, auto complete him first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes a certain amount of sense – implemented!

I still suggest reading stuff you're posting, though :)

Comment: never ... that goes against every va